# Proving the equality $]a,b]=\cap_{n \ge 1} ]a, b+\frac 1 n[$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I need some help proving the following simple equality :  $]a,b]=\bigcap_{n \ge 1} ]a, b+\frac 1 n[$. $\subset$ is obvious as $\forall n$ we have $]a,b] \subset ]a, b+\frac 1 n[$. But how does one prove the reverse?

Comment: Suppose $x \in \bigcap\limits_{n\geqslant 1} ]a,b+\frac1n[$. what can you say about $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For each $x>b$ there is $n$ such that $x$ does not belong to $ ]a, b+\frac 1 n[$.

Comment: Assume that there exists an $x > b \not\in ]a,b]$ that is in $\cap_{n \ge 1} ]a,b+\frac 1 n[$ but then we can find an $n$ such that $x$ does not belong to $]a, b + \frac 1 n[$. Contradiction. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $c < b+\frac1n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $c\le b$.